# How to convert array of words into sentence?

Tags: arrays, json, stringify

Given a long, long, long array (length of a 300 pages book), conceptually such as :

```
["我","是","拖拉机","学院","手","扶","拖拉机","专
业","的","。","不用","多久","，","我","就","会升",
"职加薪","，","当上","CEO","，","走上","人生",
"巅峰","。"]
```

**How to efficiently convert this array into a space-separated string ?** Such as:

var str = "我 是 拖拉机 学院 手 扶 拖拉机 专业 的 。 不用 多久 ， 我 就 会升 职加薪 ， 当上 CEO ， 走上 人生 巅峰 。"

---

**Edit:**

I currently have 2 demo approaches of unknown efficiency :

```
// For loop
for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) { res = res +' '+input[i]; }; break;
//or
// JSON.stringify() + replace()
JSON.stringify(input).replace(/","|\["|"\]/g, ' ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```js
let arr = ["我","是","拖拉机","学院","手","扶","拖拉机","专业","的","。","不用","多久","，","我","就","会升",
"职加薪","，","当上","CEO","，","走上","人生",
"巅峰","。"]

console.log(arr.join(' '))
```

Comment: Oh god. I couldnt come with that! Thank you.